# How to parse the values to string in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to parse this double format values (distance, calories) into string format? They are taken in textBlock. need to convert them into string in button clickevent.

```
private void PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {            
            var coord = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
     var calories = caloriesLabel.Text;
                var previousPoint = _line.Path.Last();
                var distance = coord.GetDistanceTo(previousPoint);
                var millisPerKilometer = (1000.0 / distance) * (System.Environment.TickCount - _previousPositionChangeTick);
                _kilometres += distance / 1000.0;               
                paceLabel.Text = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisPerKilometer).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
                distanceLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f2} km", _kilometres);
                caloriesLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:f0}", _kilometres * 65);
}
```

Comment: What are you looking to do, parse the string values back to doubles once they've been text in the textBlocks?

Comment: @caschw : they are in double format. So i need them to be changed into string format to post them into the next screen for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use,
example,

```
double d = 13.000;
string.Format("{0:0.000}km", d)
```

or You could pass the format parameter to ToString method.

```
string s = d.ToString("0.000 km");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

if "0.000" is not passed as a parameter then only 13 will be displayed.Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to do a tryparse.

```
String Dist, Cals;

bool distParsed = Double.TryParse(distance,out Dist);
bool calsParsed = Double.TryParse(calories,out Cals);

if(!distParsed||!calseParsed)
{
  String message = !distParsed ? "Distance failed to parse" : "";
  if(message.Trim().Length==0)
    message = !calsParsed ? "Calories failed to parse" : "";
  MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```